# Cronatab -e raises this error: /tmp/crontab.JS8BKY: No such file or directory Creation of temporary crontab file failed - aborting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, whenever

I am using Whenever gem for scheduling jobs. But when my job get executed it raises *Jan  3 16:05:01 Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal CRON[17544]: (CRON) error (create tmpfile)* this error.

Comment: hmm.  Does your system have a `/tmp` and is it acessible by the user running `crontab -e `?

Comment: yes, my system has /tmp. And I have two servers. On other server I can run _crontab -e_. But On this server it troughs thsi error.

Comment: and the user running `crontab -e` can write to it?

Comment: check your log once in cron.log "sudo tail -f /var/log/cron.log"

Comment: sudo  grep CRON /var/log/syslog Jan  3 16:20:41 Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal cron[21520]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Jan  3 16:20:41 Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal cron[21520]: (CRON) INFO (Skipping @reboot jobs -- not system startup)
Jan  3 16:25:01 Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal CRON[23038]: (CRON) error (create tmpfile)
Jan  3 16:25:01 Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal CRON[23039]: (CRON) error (create tmpfile)
Jan  3 16:26:01 Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal CRON[23286]: (CRON) error (create tmpfile)

Comment: sudo tail -f /var/log/cron.log 
_Jan  3 16:25:01 Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal CRON[23039]: (CRON) error (create tmpfile)
Jan  3 16:26:01 Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal CRON[23286]: (CRON) error (create tmpfile)
Jan  3 16:35:01 Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal CRON[25570]: (CRON) error (create tmpfile)
Jan  3 16:45:01 Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal CRON[28025]: (CRON) error (create tmpfile)_

Comment: Maybe tmp folder don't have much space to run your command. df -h to check space avail in tmp

Comment: deploy@Ubuntu-1604-xenial-64-minimal:~$ df -h
_Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             32G     0   32G   0% /dev
tmpfs           6.3G  642M  5.7G  10% /run
/dev/md2        197G   30G  158G  16% /
tmpfs            32G  4.0K   32G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md1        488M  318M  145M  69% /boot
tmpfs           6.3G     0  6.3G   0% /run/user/1000_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

1. umount /tmp  or umount overflow
2. restart server

If still problem occurs then please restart you machine once.

Comment: just restarting the server worked for me (without unmounting)

Answer (score 2):

Actually main reason was same suggested by @jyoti. My tmp folder was out of memory. And this happens often with servers as we never reboot them. So just reboot your server and your /tmp will automatically cleared.